# Realme C2 phone bricked, bootloader locked, can't access fastboot or recovery mode, not getting connected to PC

Tags: boot, realme

My Realme C2 phone has been bricked, it had bootloader locked, and I can't go to fastboot or recovery mode, it is not getting connected to PC.

After booting the phone, it shows this screen and not doing anything next.

[image]

> The current image(boot/recovery) have been destroyed and can not boot.
> Please flash the correct image or contact customer service to fix it.

I want to flash stock ROM but not able to do it because it's not connecting to the PC.

Comment: Have you tried to go into fastboot/bootloader mode? (hold Volume Up + Power button while booting). Fastboot needs special fastboot drivers installed on Windows.

Comment: How did you flash it previously on locked bootloader?